# C# - Changing Windows Folder Option Setting

Tags: c#, view, directory, registry

I need to be able to have access to a hidden file and if I try to access it without the appropriate setting set, I will get an access error. Is there a way to change this option: http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/658/captureplz.png through C# code?

I am guessing the Registry, but I'm not sure where this would be.

Comment: Changing this setting will not affect your code _at all_.

Comment: The ImageShack image is MIA.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler A lot of images died in the great ImageShack purge. ):

Comment: @Eaton — which is why links other than to imgur are generally not favoured; they are too apt to go missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting has nothing to do with the access error your getting. This option is what the user of the computer sees and does not effect your application whatsoever.

Maybe you could provide some more information about the specific error message your seeing. The error is probably resulting from your application not have the correct permissions to access a file. [Check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429864/c-file-directory-permissions) about requesting file permissions.

Comment: Really? Hm, I will have to look over my code later. But I think that permission page may fix it, thank you.