# programatically removing "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent" checkbox using C#

Tags: c#, .net, file-permissions

I have a requirement in my application to iterate through all the sub-folders
programatically removing "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent" check box using C#.
[image]

And also convert and add the inherited parent permissions as explicit permissions on the folder.

Can any one let me know ? how can i do it in C#.

Comment: This sounds like an odd requirement. Are you sure that the person delivering this requirement actually understands NT security?

Comment: Have look at http://www.redmondpie.com/applying-permissions-on-any-windows-folder-using-c/ and http://weblogs.asp.net/cumpsd/archive/2004/02/08/69403.aspx or check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429864/c-file-directory-permissions. Hope they give you some idea

Comment: well, we have the requirement to remove everyone group from the sub directories and keep the group on the parent. So, this everyone group should be removed from sub directories which was a inherited property for the sub directories along with some other groups. So, first want to remove this everyone group.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`ObjectSecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string path = @"...";
FileSecurity fs = File.GetAccessControl(path);
fs.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false);
File.SetAccessControl(path, fs);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried to use RemoveAccessRule and RemoveAccessRuleAll but did not work for me. Maybe because those were inherited rights?