# How to see whether "include inheritable permissions" is unchecked for a file or folder?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, permissions, filesystems

I'm writing a little utility in C# to make sure a specified folder and all of its contents have appropriate access rights (I want to give the `Authenticated Users` group full access). The following code seems to work properly for updating the top level folder's ACL (Access Control List):

```
SecurityIdentifier allUsers = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null);
InheritanceFlags iFlags = InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit;
FileSystemAccessRule newRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(allUsers,
    FileSystemRights.FullControl, iFlags,
    PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow);

DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
DirectorySecurity security = info.GetAccessControl();
security.AddAccessRule(newRule);
info.SetAccessControl(security);
```

I've noticed, however, that this new access rule doesn't propagate to subfolders that have the "Include inheritable permissions …" option unchecked in their security properties. That only makes sense. So, what I want to do is turn security permission inheritance back on for any such subfolders.

My digging has uncovered the [`ObjectSecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection.aspx) method which should be half of what I need. However, it seems sloppy to just blindly use the above method on objects that already inherit their parent's DACL. Thus, I want to determine which objects have their permission inheritance turned off, but I can't seem to find the corresponding method or property which returns this information. Is there one? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why does it matter if a parent folder already has it set? Setting it again shouldn't cause any grief.

Comment: @M.Babcock – For practical reasons it seems wasteful and inefficient to force an update to a file or folder that doesn't need updating. In my specific case, there are only a few subfolders that *don't* inherit access rights, but there are hundreds or even thousands of files within those same folders that *do*. For performance reasons I would much rather update a handful of these objects than all of them.

Comment: Though not a duplicate, it is the inverse of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574196/programatically-removing-include-inheritable-permissions-from-this-objects-par

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C#'s `DirectorySecurity` class now appears to include the `AreAccessRulesProtected` property which returns `true` when inheritance is `disabled`, and `false` when inheritance is `enabled`.

As a result, you can simply use:

```
DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(pathToDir);
var isInheritanceEnabled = !dirSecurity.AreAccessRulesProtected
```

Thanks to [@Wizou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082320/how-to-see-whether-include-inheritable-permissions-is-unchecked-for-a-file-or#comment93481447_25751983)'s comment here for the heads-up!

Comment: I thought that too, but in some cases the flag AreAccessRulesProtected does not work properly. I'm in the middle of debugging my program and I got situation when dirSecurity.AreAccessRulesProtected is false and dirSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount))[0].isInherited is true! in the windows I can clearly see that inheritance is enabled and there are only inherited permissions.

Answer (score 5):

I remember using something like this:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"e:\test1");
DirectorySecurity acl = d.GetAccessControl();
if (acl.GetAccessRules(false, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier)).Count >0)
    // -- has inherited permissions
else
    // -- has no inherited permissions
```

I was also trying to find a method to check for this but I couldn't find any (even in C++). So I ended up using the code above. It worked like a charm.

Comment: It seems like an oversight from MS to not provide a more direct method to check this, but this is exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Your example does show only `if threre is something inherited` and `does not show if inheriting is switched on`. This is a difference when the parent folder does propagate rights only to the parent folder (and not to subfolders or files) or when the acl is corrupted. In both cases you will get `no inheritance even when it is turned on`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is a managed way to do this:

```
DirectorySecurity ds = System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl(@"C:\test");
byte[] rawBytes = ds.GetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm();
RawSecurityDescriptor rsd = new RawSecurityDescriptor(rawBytes, 0);

if ((rsd.ControlFlags & ControlFlags.DiscretionaryAclProtected) == 
                        ControlFlags.DiscretionaryAclProtected)
{
    // "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent" is unchecked
}
else
{
    // "Include inheritable permissons from this object's parent" is checked
}
```

Comment: It seems your code can be replaced by `ds.AreAccessRulesProtected`