# How do you deselect "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent" using VB?

Tags: vb.net

I have a requirement to create a directory, deselect the checkbox, and add read rights to the directory and all children for a specific group.  Basically what I need to do is break inheritance from the parent and create special permissions to a targeted group in VB.  I have imported the following:

```
Imports System.Security 
Imports System.Security.AccessControl 
Imports System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity
```

I tried using RemoveAccessRuleAll in the DirectorySecurity class without success.  I'm hoping someone will suggest the right class library I should be using and supply a brief example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be using [SetAccessRuleProtection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim ds As DirectorySecurity = IO.Directory.GetAccessControl(path)
ds.SetAccessRuleProtection(True, False) 'second False is for preserveInheritance
IO.Directory.SetAccessControl(path, ds)
```

Used this example (C#):

- [programatically removing "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent" checkbox using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574196/programatically-removing-include-inheritable-permissions-from-this-objects-par)

**EDIT:**

Example of adding permissions to a folder:

```
ds.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule("domain1\testuser",
                 FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow))
```

Comment: Works great.  That answers the first part of the question.

Comment: @kenw: So now you wanna know how to set permissions on a folder? Example on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d49cww7f(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2